# PuTTY timed out error after setting the httpd_can_network_connect to 1

Tags: centos, networking, putty

After installing CentOS 7, I didn't touch anything. PuTTY can connect CentOS 7 server. But, after setting

```
#setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

PuTTY (on Windows 10) cannot connect to CentOS 7 server.
The error is `"connection timed out"`

I tried:

```
#setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 0 
#systemctl stop firewalld
#setenforce 0
```

But still PuTTY cannot connect to CentOS7 server.

`ping 192.168.0.33` result is "can not connect to destination host".
`tracert 192.168.0.33` result is "can not connect to destination host"

Comment: Are you connecting *from* CentOS 7 (to what?) or *to* CentOS 7 (from what?) What have you done to try to diagnose the problem? `ping`? treacroute? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: my diagnose  is
#setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 0
or
#systemctl stop firewalld
or
#setenforce 0

Comment: So, what happens when you try to `ping` the server from the (Windows) client?  Can you run traceroute?

Comment: ping 192.168.0.33 result is "can not connect to destination host" , and tracert 192.168.0.33 result is "can not connect to destination host"

Comment: Thanks for responding. Now ***[edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/381337/edit)*** to include all that information — anything that might be helpful to anybody who tries to answer the question.